# How can I configure AspectMock with Codeception and no framework?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, autoload, codeception

I am trying to configure AspectMock and have looked through the docs and a few tutorials/sample code chunks ([this](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/10/php-getting-aspectmock-to-work.html), [this](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/php-code-is-now-99-testable-with-aspectmock-acb2860aaf44) and [this](https://www.slideshare.net/BryceEmbry/aspectmock)) which all add a piece to the puzzle. As with most folks who struggle with AspectMock, I'm sure it's a config error. I am trying to mock both a custom class of my own as well as a class from the `vendor` folder. Here goes an example of a custom class:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; // composer autoload

$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'appDir' => __DIR__ . '/..',
    'debug' => true,
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__ . '../vendor/mailjet'],
    'excludePaths' => [__DIR__, '../vendor/codeception', '../vendor/phpunit'],
    'cacheDir' => '/tmp/somewhere'
]);

// library/Dumb.php
class Dumb
{
    protected $some_var;

    public function someMethod()
    {
        codecept_debug('original Dumb->someMethod() called');

        return 'called original someMethod';
    }
}

// LibraryFunctionTest.php
public function testDumbMock(): void
{
    $double = test::double('Dumb', [
        'someMethod' => function () {
            codecept_debug('stubbed  method called');
            return 'stubbed!';
        }
    ]);

    codecept_debug($double);

    $new_dumb = new Dumb();
    codecept_debug($new_dumb);
    $new_dumb->someMethod();
    $double->verifyInvoked('someMethod');
}
```

and the output:

```
- LibraryFunctionTest: Dumb mock  AspectMock\Proxy\ClassProxy Object
  (
      [reflected:protected] => ReflectionClass Object
          (
              [name] => Dumb
          )

      [className] => Dumb
      [invokedFail:protected] => Expected %s to be invoked but it never occurred. Got: %s
      [notInvokedMultipleTimesFail:protected] => Expected %s to be invoked %s times but it never occurred.
      [invokedMultipleTimesFail:protected] => Expected %s to be invoked but called %s times but called %s.
      [neverInvoked:protected] => Expected %s not to be invoked but it was.
  )

  Dumb Object
  (
      [some_var:protected] => 
  )

  original Dumb->someMethod() called
✖ LibraryFunctionTest: Dumb mock (0.01s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 125 ms, Memory: 16.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) LibraryFunctionTest: Dumb mock
 Test  tests/unit/library/FunctionsTest.php:testDumbMock
Expected Dumb::someMethod to be invoked but it never occurred. Got:
```

As you can see, Aspect mock appears to be mocking the `Dumb` class, but when I try to create an instance of `Dumb` and invoke `someMethod()` it uses the original object definition.

When I run a similar test against a class in the MailJet library I have loaded via composer, I get the same thing: I can't seem to create an instance of the mocked object.

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, it was a config error in `bootstrap.php`

1) My own class

The solution was with autoloading - which I confess I didn't really understand and am not using since my app is entirely procedural with no custom classes at all. I just needed to add the following line to the end of `bootstrap.php`

```
$kernel->loadFile(__DIR__ . '/../library/Dumb.php');
```

which (I believe) instructs AspectMock to do it's magic and mess with the internals of this class. This autoload stuff *is* in the documentation, but I didn't understand it, and no error was thrown.

2) The MailJet class

The problem was with the `includePaths` directive. I was missing an extra slash in the path. The solution was:

```
'includePaths' => [__DIR__ . '/../vendor/mailjet'],
'excludePaths' => [__DIR__, '/../vendor/codeception', '/../vendor/phpunit'],
```

The documentation *has* the leading slash, so again, it's my fault. However, it would have been a lot easier to debug if an error had been thrown alerting me to this error. I feel like I tried a zillion (wrong) combinations of these paths before stumbling on this.